# как данные из VueI18n добавить в массив

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-cli, i18n

Пример того как можно вставлять данные в html: `<p class="text__black font-weight-bold">{{ $vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.textData.clientId') }}</p>`

Нужно сделать вместо: `emptyRules: [(v) => !!v || "Это поле является обязательным"]`
Типо этого чтобы она брала данные из другого компонента: `emptyRules: [(v) => !!v || {{ $vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.textData.emptyRules') }}]` Но это работает только внутри html, а не в массиве
как использовать эту конструкцию из i18n `{{ $vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.textData.clientId') }}`  ???

Comment: `this.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.textData.clientId')`? (Насчёт того, что в кавычках не уверен, если это переменная, то тоже с `this`)